# Querying an MS Access database from Python on 64-bit Windows

Tags: sql, python-2.7, ms-access, x86-64, windows-7-x64

How do I query an Access *.mdb database from Python 2.7?

Additional info: I'm on a 64-bit Windows 7 OS (It's important because all the other answers I found on Stack Overflow are for 32-bit.)

Edit: I have 32-bit Office 2010 installed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate whether you have MS Office installed on the machine. If you do have Office installed, be sure to mention **(1)** which version of Office (... 2007? ... 2010?) and **(2)** whether it is the 32-bit or the 64-bit build.

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=python%202.7%20odbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 32-bit Office installed on your machine so you need to use a 32-bit version of Python to manipulate your database file(s). You should be able to confirm the bit-ness of your Python by simply starting it up, e.g.,

```
C:\Users\Gord>python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

You also need an ODBC component for Python. I recommend [pypyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/). The main pypyodbc page has sample code, and there is also a tutorial [here](http://www.next-second.com/s/pypyodbc_tutorial_en.htm).